# State is not updating on axios call post Next js

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js, state

i'm developing an ecommerce whit Nextjs and payments with Paypal.
This is my product component

```
const Product = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id, category } = router.query;
  const [product, setProduct] = useState();
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (category) {
      const foundProduct = products[category].find(
        (element) => element.id == id
      );
      setProduct({ ...foundProduct, amount, total: foundProduct.price * amount });
    }
  }, [id, amount]);

  
  return (
    <>
      {!product ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <div className="product-wrapper">
          <div className="product-image">
            <Image src={product.image} />
          </div>
          <div className="product-info">
            <h3>{product.title}</h3>
            <p className="product-price">
              {product.currency} {product.price}
            </p>
            <p className="product-description">
              {product.description}
            </p>
            <div className="product-cart-container">
              <div className="product-cart-handle">
                <p onClick={() => amount > 1 && setAmount(amount - 1)}>-</p>
                <span>{amount}</span>
                <p onClick={() => setAmount(amount + 1)}>+</p>
              </div>
              <BuyButtton item={product} amount={amount} />
            </div>
            <div className="product-general">
              <p>General information</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

and this is my BuyButton component

```
const BuyButtton = ({ item }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(item);
  }, [item]);
  return (
    <div>
      <PayPalScriptProvider
        options={{
          "client-id":"",
        }}
      >
        <PayPalButtons
          createOrder={async () => {
            try {
              const res = await axios({
                url: "http://localhost:3000/api/payment",
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                  Accept: "application/json",
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(item),
              });
              return res.data.id;
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
          }}
          onApprove={(data, actions) => {
            console.log(data);
            actions.order.capture();
          }}
          style={{ layout: "horizontal", color: "blue" }}
        />
      </PayPalScriptProvider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

So when i pass this props item to my BuyButton component works fine, the amount and total value updates correctly, the problem is when i do the axios call, it looks like the component stores the initial value of the item prop, so amount and value never changes, its always amount:1, value:item.value. Any ideas? Thanks

I tried storing the item prop in a state but it didin't work as i expected

Comment: The `BuyButton` needs to read the `amount` along with item and pass the `amount` in the axios calls.

Comment: @AnthonyC i don't get it, how do i do that? buybuttons reads amount but not in the axios call

Answer (score 0):

The solution that solved my problem was adding forceReRender prop to PayPalButtons like this forceReRender={[item]}, so it re-render the button and gets the new amount value

Answer (score 0):

In the `Product` component, you are passing `item` & `amount` to `BuyButton`

`<BuyButtton item={product} amount={amount} />`.

You need to add the `amount` to the BuyButton component as well.

`const BuyButtton = ({ item, amount }) => {`

and pass the amount in the request body in the axios call

```
data: JSON.stringify(item),
// need to add the amount data
```